# Can't capture the ouput of the paste bash command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
( ping -n apple.com | ack -o --flush '((?<=icmp_seq=)[0-9]+|(?<=time=)[0-9]+[.][0-9]+)' | paste - - ) > ~/Desktop/ping_ouput.txt
```

Doesn't seem to be working for some reason, whereas if I take away the

```
| paste - -
```

section, it works just fine. I need to join every other line together with a tab instead of newline. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: what does "doesn't work"  mean? What is the output? could it be an issue with stdin and stderror?

Comment: It's not outputting to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

**By default, `ping` produces output *indefinitely, until terminated***, so your pipe will keep producing output and growing the output file indefinitely, and **your command will never finish by itself**.

Thus, **you need to *limit* the number of pings performed**; e.g.:

- using the `-c count` option to stop after the specified number of pings.
- alternatively, on BSD-like systems, you can use `-o` to stop after the first *successful* ping.
- alternatively, you can stop after a specified *timeout in seconds*, regardless of how many packets were received:

  - Linux:  `-w timeout`
  - BSD-like systems: `-t timeout`

Incidentally, in order to redirect a pipeline to a file, there's *no* need to enclose it in `(...)` as a whole, which needlessly creates a(nother) *subshell*.

---

<sup>The following was written before (a) the specific symptom was known and (b) before the OP revealed in a comment that their platform is OSX. The commands below show alternatives to the OP's extraction command; `-c 2` has been added to limit ping to *2* attempts.</sup>

[tivn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30145125/45375) has found at least *potential* problem in your command: the assumption that `time` values *always* have a decimal point, which does not hold on *Linux* platforms; on BSD/OSX platforms, however, there are *always* 3 decimal places.

You can bypass this issue as well as the need to merge consecutive lines as follows (I'm using `127.0.0.1` instead of `apple.com` for easier testing):

Using either GNU `sed` (Linux) or BSD `sed` (BSD-like systems, including OSX):

```
ping -c 2 -n 127.0.0.1 |
  sed -E '1d; s/^.* icmp_seq=([^ ]+).* time=([^ ]+).*$/\1'$'\t''\2/'
```

---

Alternative solutions, using `awk`:

```
ping -c 2 -n 127.0.0.1 | awk -F'[ =]' -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1 { print $6, $10 }'
```

---

If you'd rather not rely on field *indices*, here's an alternative (still relies on field `icmp_seq` to come *before* `time`, and for both to be preceded by a space):

```
ping -c 2 -n 127.0.0.1 | awk -F' (icmp_seq|time)=' -v OFS='\t' '
  NR>1 { sub(" .+$", "", $2); sub(" .+$", "", $3)
  print $2, $3 }'
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide sample input you got from the `ping`, so it is not clear what your problem is. But I guess your issue is because the `time` part from `ping` result may not always contains dot `.`, for example: `64 bytes from x.x.x.x: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=137 ms` . You may want to try with the following command :

```
( ping -n yahoo.com \
  | ack -o --flush '((?<=icmp_seq=)\d+|(?<=time=)[\d.]+)' \
  | stdbuf -o0 paste - - \
) > ~/Desktop/ping_ouput.txt
```

Edit: after comment from OP, the issue may actually come from buffered `paste` command. Please try with adding `stdbuf -o0` to the `paste` command.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But your prescribed solution isn't outputting to the file either. The main problem for me has been that the paste - - portion keeps it from saving the output to ping_output.txt

Comment: Good catch; times >= 100 ms. indeed seem to be represented as _integers_ overall on _Linux_ (there's nothing obvious in the `man` page that would tell us that). By contrast, on BSD/OSX systems, there are _always_ 3 decimal places.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for checking other system. I only check with Linux.

Comment: @zacbrac, Perhaps you have `paste` that is buffered, try replace it with `stdbuf -o0 paste - -`

Comment: My pleasure; @zacbrac: you must ensure that `ping` _terminates,_ otherwise your pipe will keep writing to the output file _indefinitely_; see my update.

Comment: @tivn stdbuf doesn't seem to come with mac os x(which I'm using), is there a different argument that I can pass for BSD-like paste which will keep it from buffering?

Comment: @zacbrac: Buffering isn't the issue. The question is: after how many ping attempts do you want to be done? Unless you limit the number of pings, your command will _never_ finish by itself.

Comment: @mklement0 Ahh, that was it. Thank you so much. It's all working now. Now I can plot this in gnuplot :)

Comment: @zacbrac you're welcome. solutions from mklement0 also worth trying.